# Flutter shadow looks ugly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My card decoration shadow doesn't look like a shadow and more like a ugly border. I have no idea how to make it look like a natural shadow.

code:

```
var boxShadow = BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          spreadRadius: 0,
          blurRadius: 1,
          offset: Offset(3, 10), // changes position of shadow
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Comment: see [kElevationToShadow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/kElevationToShadow-constant.html) sources

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Material` Widget instead of Container and its `elevation` property for shadow instead.

Or provide more code and better description if you want me to explain what's your problem. Preferably Github link or your whole build function.